# count with a function in panda

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having real fun with groupby function in pandas, please advice on how to apply functions on groupby? Such as, I want to know how many rows grouped by track_id satisfies the `rule_1==4` or anything in general.

```
df.groupby('track_id')['rule_1'].count()
```

I want to know rule_1 which equals some value.

> I tried this - `df.groupby('track_id')['rule_1'==4].count()`

Is there a callback function or anything simpler ?

Comment: Generally you filter your data before you group it

Comment: yes, I agree, now my mind flashed! I was thinking all way around.. thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check

```
df['rule_1'].eq(4).groupby(df['track_id']).sum()
```